# Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 is not recognized the name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure-data-factory

I am trying to use the preview version of data factory. However, when I try to create an new data factory with Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2 command in PowerShell. 
It returns a error: The term "Set-AzureRmDataFactoryV2" is not recognized the name of a cmdlet. Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: @mark, it works now, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you have installed AzureRM PowerShell V4.4.1 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-azurerm-ps?view=azurermps-4.4.1